# What is a 1-tree bound?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, trees

What does it mean exactly to find 1-tree bound? Is it an optimal TSP tour? and how would one find find an even better lower bound tour than the optimal one? is it possible?

Thanks to all who can answer!

Comment: This is one way to obtain an upper bound. Lower bounds are given by a explicit tour (which is not necessarily optimal). In general, 1-tree bound is not optimal. The better lower (or upper) bound is the optimal solution, so by definition, it is not possible to do better.

Comment: @caduk Okay so if am asked to find a better one, that means an optimal one. But how to find one in general? I have a TSP but what makes it 1-tree-bound?

Comment: An optimal bound does not mean anything, this is equivalent to find the optimal solution of the TSP. But you can generate better bounds (for example, the Held-Karp bound). I don't know what it means for TSP to be 1-tree-bound, the 1-tree-bound is an algorithm which gives you an upper bound, not an instance of TSP.